# pyspark read json file as one column of stringType

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to convert a JSON file to a list of rows of the full JSON string. I would use the text format to read the JSON files, but these files are not newline separated and I can't change that.

Input JSON:

```json
{"key":"value1"},{"key":"value2"}
```

Expected Output:

| record |
| --- |
| {"key":"value1"} |
| {"key":"value2"} |

Comment: Can you show an example of th json, also the epxected output ? what have you tried ?

Comment: can't sadly show the JSON but I can make a mock of what it should look like.

`{"key":"value1"},{"key":"value2"}`

output should be: 
`record               |`
`----------------`
`{"key":"value1"}`
`----------------`
`{"key":"value2"}`

Comment: basically I need for each record of the JSON to be converted to one whole String in one column

Comment: Can you please add it to the question and format it so it can be readable ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using

```
df = spark.read.options(lineSep = ",").json(filePathOfJson)
```

By default it is "\n"